# Git Merge fails to update some files

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

When I merge a features branch to master:

```
git checkout master
git merge features/myfeature
```

I find that some files have been merged, but some haven't. `master` has merges from other feature branches so I don't want to force merge `features/myfeature` to `master`. When I look at the `.git` folder, I see this:

`.MERGE_MSG.swn`
`.MERGE_MSG.swo`
`.MERGE_MSG.swp`

Are the merge files somehow causing the issue? How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have merge conflicts? Should show ' | MERGING' next to your branch name.

Comment: Also, if you call `> git status` what do you get?

Comment: First question: I'm not sure what you mean by "force merge"; there is no `force` option to the `merge` command. I also can't think of any standard operation in which your merge would override or conflict with other merges that have happened, so I'm not sure what your concern is there.  Can you clarify what command you are talking about?

Comment: Second question: when you say some files "aren't merged"... what is the resulting state of those files?  Are there changes from one branch or the other that are being discarded?  More generally, what are you seeing that leads you to say that some files are merged and some not?

Comment: Files named `.swp`, `.swo`, and so on are created by vim as a sort of "advisory lock" that tells you that another vim is already editing that file and maybe you should not edit it again (and vim also stores the recovery data here, should vim crash or be killed). That there are *three* of them implies that you have a lot of simultaneous merges running that you have never finished, or that you have a buggy vim, or something. (The normal single file is `.swp` and if you already have one, the second one is `.swo` and the third is `.swn`.)

Comment: @BrandonK No merge conflicts. git status is "Your branch is ahead of x commits" (I haven't pushed yet)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger When I said it's not merged, I meant that some files still have the version that `master` has although the merge from the feature to master branch appears to be successful.

Comment: On examining further, it appears to be 1 file that's missing the updates from feature to master. Very weird. Tried merge multiple times and I get back a `Already up-to-date`